# Trouble setting content-type in Hapi.js for image

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, hapi.js

I am using an image manipulation library(Sharp) to manipulate a image file dynamically (getAvatar()). It returns a buffer via Promise with which I reply a request.

```
 const imageBuffer = getAvatar(options, username);
  reply(imageBuffer)
  .type('image/png');
```

Every thing runs fine and the image is also rendered in browser but I get a console warning in chrome as follows.

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "http://localhost:3000/avatar/johndoe".
```

Comment: How are you requesting this image, via ajax? What's the Content-Type of the request?

Comment: Not Ajax, just dumb browser GET request, through address bar.

Comment: You need to put that url in an `<img src=x />` tag since it doesn't have an image extension the browser assumes what will be returned is html (text content). If you were requesting jondoe.png you wouldn't have that issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if setting .png helps since I tried with no result(same issue), for example https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/github its renders inline in browser and there is no console warning. I'm trying to implement the same.

Comment: Never mind I found that on disabling cache for github avatars, even it has the same problem. On enabling caching subsequent requests don't give that error.